# What is the equivalent of #page & #page-wrapper in Bootstrap theme?

Tags: 7, theming

In most of the Drupal themes I find the IDs `#page` and `#page-wrapper`, but it is not available in the [Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap).

I tried to find in theme, but maximum I could find is class `.container` but is covers only that particulate section i.e. header, main-content, footer.

Is there any ID or class in Bootstrap theme which covers entire webpage like `#page` does in almost all other themes OR if there is not how can I add that?

*To experiment*, I did try to add following to `page.tpl.php` like other themes,

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div id="page">
```

And added following CSS to check,

```
#page {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
#page-wrapper {
    border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

But it applies to border of the browser not to actual width of the page  as shown in the following image.

> [image]

Hence looks like this way we can not add this to Bootstrap theme.

Any idea or suggestion how to apply #page and #page-wrapper to Bootstrap theme? Thanks.

Comment: No, there isn't any id or wrapper equivalent to #page or #page-wrapper. Saying so, what is exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MalabyaTewari In process of styling the theme. I wan to add  the page-border and other stuff around the entire-webpage, So I need some Id or class which represent that. In all other theme, most of it is #page and #page-wrapper, but as you said it is not available, might be equivalent also not available. Even I try to add by looking at otehr theme as mentioned in my question. is there way to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several try and error method, I did find the solution for this.

For a note, I am using LESS.

**Step-1:** Add a `<div>` to `page.tpl.php`

Add following code in the `page.tpl.php` file of your sub-theme.

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div id="page">
```

**Step-2:** Add the following CSS in the `style.less` of your sub-theme.

```
@media(min-width:@screen-sm-min) {
      #page-wrapper {
      width: @container-tablet;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border: 1px solid red; }
    }
@media(min-width:@screen-md-min) {
      #page-wrapper {
      width: @container-desktop;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border: 1px solid red;}
    }
@media(min-width:@screen-lg-min) {   
      #page-wrapper {
      width: @container-large-desktop;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border: 1px solid red;}
    }
```

*So, this way, the added `<div>` will be in harmony of Responsive theme of bootstrap and it will not displace any other container in the site and will not interfere with the native responsive design of Bootstrap.*

> [image]

**Further Any suggestion or comment are welcome.**